# Customize destination of Redis' RDB file

Tags: redis

I want to customize the destination of Redis' RDB file to be something other than a file on a mounted file system.
For example:

- Send the file to a remote host via scp
- Upload the file to Hadoop HDFS (I'm running Redis on a Hadoop cluster, in which we use HDFS for backup all the time)
- gzip the file and then move it to some archive location

The reason for this is I want to archive the RDB files (my data gets flushed out every day). I'm not sure what I'm going to do with these archived RDB files yet, but I think I'll be able to derive some value from them later.

Is there a way to trigger an external process from Redis when a new dump is made so that I can ship the RDB file to its destination? The most sophisticated thing I can come up with right now is a cron job that checks to see if the file needs to be shipped ever minute or so, but I'd rather have it triggered instead of constantly polling.

I'm pretty new to Redis, so feel free to correct me if you think I'm approaching this problem improperly and suggest a new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, if you're doing this to preserve data that is going to be wiped out, why not just schedule it to scp it and gzip it right before the days data is flushed?  What is the reason for wanting it not to live on a normal file system?  To my knowledge there is no way to trigger an external process from within redis when it writes the RDB file.  It's going to potentially happen quite frequently depending on your `save` settings in the config file.  Take a look at this doc to get more information http://redis.io/topics/persistence.

Comment: You aren't missing too much. If you really want me to explain more, I will, but I'm satisfied if you don't know of a trigger because I can't find information on one, either. I just wanted some confirmation that I should go down another path before doing so. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @orangeoctopus ok, I had another thought.  Maybe you could script something to watch the monitor command output, it might show you when the saves happen (not sure if it does). At least that way you're not constantly polling. Of course if you're adventurous and decent with c++ you could always add something into the bgsave/save routine that will push a notification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does show when the saves happen. That is actually quite clever. I'll dig around the save code and see if I could add in a pluggable trigger interface. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing too, but:

You can change where the file is made in redis.conf

You can set up crontab that move/copy the file.

For highest security, do two crontabs - one that move the file (mv data.rdb data1.rdb) and second that upload data1.rdb 5-10 min later. Reason is that it may be possible the crontab to start at the same time as Redis save process.

Because topic is interesting, I may do simple script that do this,
check http://redis4you.com/articles.php tomorrow.

Comment: Here is the article / script I promised -
**Redis save and backup script**: 
http://redis4you.com/articles.php?id=010&name=Redis+save+and+backup+script